# textchange event to filter datagridview asp.net using RowFilter

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using below code on `TextSearch_TextChanged` of textbox to filter data of `datagridview`
but i am getting error that says

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

I tried to change the `data source` to from as `DataTable` to `dataview` but that is wont help me
any idea it not really clear error for me

**updated**
the project start and work normally untill I write something in the textbox and leave it the web page break and show that error

```
protected void TextSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LB_Message.Visible = true;
            LB_Message.Text = "I am changed !";
            if(DGV_ProductsView != null)
            {
                (DGV_ProductsView.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Product_desc like '%{0}%'", TextSearch.Text);
            }
            if (DGV_ProductsView == null) { LB_Message.Text = "i am null !!!"; }
        }
```

Comment: When are you getting the error?  When application Starts?  Before rows are added to the DataTable?  When an application starts you will get events before data is ever put into the DataTable or as DataTable is filled.  So yo uhave to test if DataSource is null and check if the number of rows in table is > 0.  Intially a datatable when constructed the row count is -1.  then when columns are added the row count goes to zero.  Finally as you add rows the count increments.

Comment: @jdweng the project start and work normally untill I write something in the `textbox` and leave it the web page break and show that error

Comment: So DGV is showing data?  You need to use instance of the classes and not the object.  Put a break point on line that fails and hover over variables to see which are null.  You really should be using the parameters sender and e to get the textbox object instead of TextSearch.Text.  The DGV_ProductsView I cannot tell from code if it is an instance of a class or a class.